# Why does pâte à choux puff up?

Tags: pastry

Why does pâte à choux puff up so perfectly?
What are the ingredients or the science behind it that can make that happen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A choux is an interesting batter that is created in a way that maximizes gluten structure. It is essentially cooked twice.  You combine and heat water and butter, then add flour and continue cooking the resulting paste. That paste forms a ball, and then several eggs are beaten in.  This batter is then piped onto a sheet and baked.  In addition to the gluten structure, the initial cooking also causes the starches to gelatinize, further reinforcing the structure.  In essence, you have created a deflated balloon.  When the piped shapes are baked, steam develops and inflates the "balloon."  [It's all explained quite clearly right here.](https://foodcrumbles.com/the-science-of-choux-pastry-in-profiteroles/)

Comment: your original link died, perhaps this one is a good replacement? https://foodcrumbles.com/the-science-of-choux-pastry-in-profiteroles/